# NSString stringWithFormat format warning

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am probably using a wrong symbol for the NSString type to be included in another string.

```
const char* error; //it's set, not nil
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat : @"Problem with SQL statement in \n %@ \n %@",sqlQuery,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error]]);
```

The expression works, but I am getting this warning:

```
Formatting string is not a string literal(potentially insecure)
```

Is there a way to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Just for starters the posted code is missing a trailing "]". As always breakup compound statements, especially when debugging. `NSLog()` after each step or use the debugger to inspect after each step.;

Comment: Do you have this whole statement within an `NSLog()`?

Comment: yes, it's in NSLog, see the edit

Comment: Get rid of *both* uses of `stringWithFormat:` and use `%s` instead of `%@` for `error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [NSLog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog) implementation, the function expects a constant string or a format specifier string as it's first argument.

You need to use:

```
NSLog(@"Problem with SQL statement in [BSurfSpotDBOperations allSpots] \n %@ \n %@",sqlQuery,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Format strings in `NSLog()` statements must be constant strings or there will be a warning. Re-write the code to make the format portion a string literal.

In general avoid complex compound statements. Temporary variables make the code more readable and potentially less buggy. The compiler is quite good at elimination temporaries at release compile-time.

Example:

```
const char* error; //it's set, not nil
NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error];
NSLog(@"Problem with SQL statement in [BSurfSpotDBOperations allSpots] \n %@ \n %@", sqlQuery, errorString);
```

Comment: Even better - get rid of `errorString` and use `%s` to directly log `error`. No need for the `NSString`.

Comment: From a debugging POV the extra statements might expose the error, perhaps it is not really set, not null terminated, etc. Note that the error statement was not included in the original question. Generally when debugging there is an incorrect assumption, verifying each step helps expose the incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithFormat` is unnecessary here since `NSLog()` gives you similar options.  You could simply change it to this:

```
NSLog(@"Problem with ... \n %@ \n %@", sqlQuery,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error]);
```

This will eliminate the warning since the NSLog knows it isn't going to run into a string literal it doesn't know what to do with, which is a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method :

```
NSLog([@"Problem with SQL statement in [BSurfSpotDBOperations allSpots] \n %@ \n %@"
,sqlQuery,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error]);
```

I think you can also translate `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:error]` by `error`

Think this can help you ;)